# Weird behavior in select/option tag in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code snippet :

```
<select class="form-control" name="" id="" ng-model="offerId">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option ng-repeat="offer in offers " value="{{ offer.id }}"
            ng-selected="offerId == offer.id">
        {{offer.supplier.name}}
        ({{offer.request.name}})
    </option>
</select>
```

It works as desired.
The problem or the weird behavior is that, if I change the ngModel(offerId) from other components/triggers, the list has a new blank space option added; which behaves just as the default "Choose" option and when any option(including the blank option) is selected from the select/option, the blank space option disappears, and other functionality is just same, JUST THE BLANK SPACE IS WEIRD.

I also used ngOptions but the functionality changed, so I want to stick with this implementation.

Is this a feature??

Some code snippet :

```
$scope.clearAttachedFiles = function () {
$scope.attachedFiles = {uploads: null, links: null};
};
$scope.$watch('offerId', function (a, b) {
if ($scope.offerId) {
offerId = $scope.offerId;
}
if ((typeof a == 'undefined' || typeof a == 'null') && (typeof b == 'undefined' || typeof b == 'null')) {
return;
}
if (a === '') {
$scope.level = 'EVENT';
$scope.privateMessage = true;
$scope.offer = null;
}
else {
$scope.level = 'OFFER';
$scope.privateMessage = false;
angular.forEach($scope.offers, function (offer) {
if (offer.id == a) {
$scope.offer = offer;
}
});
}
$scope.getPaginatedActivities();
$scope.resetActivitiesList();
$scope.currentPage = 1;
});
```

Comment: "I change the ngModel(offerId) from other components/triggers" How are you changing show the code. Also show the structure of offers array

Comment: I am changing the model from a method call in ngClick from other component. JSON structure of offers array is very long, how can I show ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using it the wrong way, ng-options is there for a reason.

When you are using ng-repeat, you are adding a watcher for each option in the array and the performance can be really bad. Also doing value={{}} will have problems because it's not the proper way to do it, depending on the compile time and other factors the select can be taking the {{}} as the value instead of the evaluated expression. Is probably the reason why the blank is selected.

Use ngOptions, is flexible and easy to make it work. Here the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Ask any question that you have related to it!!!

Comment: Ya , I did use ngOptions but the logic which was working before, didn't work. So I am with my current implementation.

Comment: So change the logic to make it work, you should use ngOptions, just paste the code and we can make it work!